# Tensorflow steps/sec gradually drops

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

Hi Tensorflow experts:

I have noticed that steps/sec of my training job with multiple workers and parameter servers tend to stabilize to a lower value than initially. Is there any explanation for that? I don't think it has to do with evaluators since I configured them to start after 1000 seconds. Also I am using tensorflow 1.12 with estimator and dataset API. Thanks!

[image: global steps / sec plot]

Comment: Many OS's will automatically deprioritize CPU-bound processes; perhaps after some seconds, your OS's scheduler notices that tensor flow is taking up lots of CPU and decides to let other processes run more often (when they want to)?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner the only other (non background) processes running concurrently are tensorboard and nuclide, which are pretty light-weight.

Comment: Could it be that your CPU is throttling, slowing down your data pipeline?

Comment: @OlivierDehaene do you know how to tell if CPU is throttling? Why would it do that? Thx